# Why are Windows XP and 7 qemu/kvm guests not recognizing updates to a local Samba share?

Tags: windows, kvm-virtualization, samba, server-message-block, qemu

I develop cross-platform software and test the Windows ports with wine, Windows XP, and Windows 7, the latter two tested using qemu with KVM. I also have several versions of OS X and Debian Wheezy as KVM VMs as well. To get to my projects from within the guests, I have a Samba share and connect to that share from within the guest using `\\10.0.2.2\src`. The two Windows VMs have this mapped to network drive `Z:`.

This has worked fine for a while on all platforms. However, after May 13, the two Windows guests aren't recognizing changes, as if they're caching the share's state on that day. Running `Z:\...\program.exe` runs the program as it was on May 13, and `dir` shows May 13 for `.`, `program.exe`, and `program.dll` but May 16 for `..`. Amazingly, this works even if the share has the directory removed!

What's going on? So far, I've tried Googling for a variety of different terms that seem related ("smb share shows old files", "clear smb cache", "disable offline files", etc.), all to no avail.

The host is Ubuntu 15.04. The qemu version is

```
QEMU emulator version 2.2.0 (Debian 1:2.2+dfsg-5expubuntu9.1), Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard
```

The samba version is 4.1.13-Ubuntu.

What's going on? Thanks.